# How to run a while loop to run a REST API call until no more results come back in Python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, get

I'm writing a short Python program to request a JSON file using a Rest API call.  The API limits me to a relatively small results set (50 or so) and I need to retrieve several thousand result sets.  I've implemented a while loop to achieve this and it's working fairly well but I can't figure out the logic for 'continuing the while loop' until there are no more results to retrieve.  Right now I've implemented a hard number value but would like to replace it with a conditional that stops the loop if no more results come back.  The 'offset' field is the parameter that the API forces you to use to specify which set of results you want in your 50.  My logic looks something like...

```html
import requests
import json
from time import sleep

url = "https://someurl"
offsetValue = 0

PARAMS = {'limit':50, 'offset':offsetValue}



headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

while offsetValue <= 1000:
   response = requests.request(
      "GET",
       url,
      headers=headers,
      params = PARAMS
   )
   testfile =  open("testfile.txt", "a")
   testfile.write(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
   testfile.close()
   offsetValue = offsetValue + 1
   sleep(1)
```

So I want to change the conditional the controls the while loop from a fixed number to a check to see if the result set for the getRequest is empty.  Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Added code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop can be `while true`. After each fetch, convert the payload to a dict. If the number of results is 0, then `break`.

Depending on how the API works, there may be other signals that there’s nothing more to fetch, e.g. some HTTP error, not necessarily the result count — you’ll have to discover the API’s logic for that.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your answer.  I've implemented much of what you suggest and have just about everything working except one thing.  When I write the results of each page call to a file I 'append' the results and unfortunately it's injecting additional {} to the JSON result set.  Any suggestions for how to write many pages of json call results to a single file (appended) without running into this issue?

Comment: Your best option is to embrace the NDJSON format (aka new line delimited JSON) if you can. That’s a file in which each line is a complete JSON object. This format is ideal for any streaming approach, and you’re basically just streaming data to a file. Works well with popular JSON tools like `jq`.